# Что такое "объективация" по отношению к женщинам. Правильно ли вообще так говорить?

Tags: значение-слов

Всё больше людей, подхватывая тему сексизма и женских прав, жалуются на какую-то объективацию (или объективизацию, тут я не уверен) женщин. Мне такое употребление режет слух. Кажется, будто это очередное модное словечко невпопад. Проясните, пожалуйста, ситуацию: можно ли так употреблять и что вообще за смысл вкладывают в это слово?

Comment: Видимо, это одностороннее восприятие в качестве _объекта_ вожделения: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Alex_aпder я так понимаю, это догадка и словарь тут не поможет?

Comment: Вероятно, это сравнительно новый социально-психологический (если не чисто феминистский) термин.